# How to select and verify the selected item in Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to check if France is selected in dropdown? The HTML is not having a selected field in the option.

```
        await driver.findElement(By.css(`select`)).click();
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//option[text()="France"]`)).click();
```

Comment: dropdown is selecting correctly but stuck in verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((async)=>{ 
await (await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//option[text()="France"]`))).click();
expect(await driver.executeScript(`return $("option:selected").text()`)).to.equal(`France`);
})();
```

`$("option:selected").text()` will return the selected value. It is a jquery syntax so, inside a executeScript and return keyword is more important